# Не работают сессии в Node js

Tags: node.js, express, express-sessions

Пользуюсь `cors` для кросбраузерных запросов.

```
import * as express from 'express';
import apiModule = require('./api/start');
import socketModule = require('./socket/start');
import conf = require('../config/config.json');
import libsModule = require('./libs/general');
import path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = conf.port;
import cors = require('cors');
import bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import session = require('express-session');


app.use(session({
    secret: "jasdfbhgsdf",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        domain: 'http://localhost:3000',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 24
    },
}));


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());


app.use('/api/', function (req, res) {
    new apiModule.Start.Run(req, res);
});
```

при `login` запросе сессия записывается

```
postLogin(req, res){
  console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!: ', req.session.user);
  if (req.session.user) {
    this.libs.resAnswer(res, {
      success: false,
      error: 'You are authorized'
    });
  } else {
    if(this.valid.username(req.body.username) && this.valid.password(req.body.password)){
      let username = req.body.username;
      let password = this.libs.getEncryptPassword(req.body.password);
      this.userLib.checkLoginUser({username: username, password: password})
          .then(result => {
            req.session.user = {id: result};
            this.libs.resAnswer(res, {
              success: true,
              data: result
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
```

но, при следующем обращении к серверу сессия пропадает.

Подскажите, что я не так делаю? Возможно вообще использовать `express-session` и `cors` одновременно?

Comment: Попробуйте после `req.session.user = {id: result};` вставить `req.session.save();`

Comment: вставил `req.session.save();` не помогло(

Comment: А вы `withCredentials` не забыли указать, когда запрос делаете,?

Comment: кукипарсер забыли? id сессии же в куки хранится, `app.use(express.cookieParser());`

Comment: добавил `cookieParser`, все равно не работает

Comment: а, кукипарсер вышел из пакета express, он отдельно так подключается - `var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');`, `app.use(cookieParser())`

Comment: все правильно, я так и подключил, иначе не работает, ошибку выбивает

Comment: Но проблема так и не решена

Comment: В англоязычном интернете похожие вопросы сводятся к порядку подключения, выжен такой порядок - куки, сесии, маршруты. Возможно куки подключили после сессии? cors не должен играть роли, кука должна встать для домена с апишкой

Comment: подправил порядок подключения, не работает, привязал сессии к `mysql`, в базе при каждом обращения к серверу на `api`  `login` записывается новый запись с  разными `session_id`. Может проблема в `cors` библиотеке?

Comment: каждый раз при обращения на сайт код `app.use(session({...}))` инициализирует  новую сессию с разными id, вот такие вот дела...( кто то может подсказать в чем дело?

Comment: тут очевидно что он не нашел у клиента куку сессии и создал новую. надо ковыряться в живом примере, создает ли хоть какаю-нибудь куку в браузере

Comment: Іван Цуркан, получилось ли у автора решить проблему?